# Is there any mechanism to connect to sql server 7 from visual studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-7

We are currently moving our SQL Server 7 based database to SQL Server 2000 (Yeah progress) However in the mean time we have to support our SQL Server 7 database product. We currently have access to Visual Studio 2008 and I know that native support of connecting to SQL Server 7 does not exist. Does anyone know of any third party solutions that will allow me to develop with visual studio 2008 and SQL Server 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the classes in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace to connect to an instance of SQL Server 7 or above.

Comment: But this will not allow me to use datasets or any of the other "nice features" in 2008

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'nice features.  You can perform all CRUD operations through the classes in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.  You will certainly be able to write code that returns the results of a query in the form of a DataSet object.